# React not rendering updated UI on state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm working on a mini project where a user shall be able to edit book info. The app presents the user with a filter to choose Fiction or Science subject category. Once chosen, he is shown a list of books where he can change the details of the book by clicking the edit button. On editing, he can choose to either save or cancel the form details. This entire workflow is on a single page! I'm using React, Redux, and Redux-form for this purpose where *component I*- Selection category (Fiction, Science), *component II*- list of books for that category and *component III*- form to edit book details. *See the attached image to imagine the app.*[image]

**Working of the app**: Once the user chooses Fiction/Science, an action is dispatched to list available books. Once he clicks Edit button for a book, another action is dispatched to display the form pre-filled with the book's values (so that the user can edit it).

**The Problem**: Unfortunately, my Edit form component is not rendering desired values due to unavailability of props to this component; even though I can see the success of my redux action with correct state/props.

**Anatomy of code**:

1. **SubjectChoice.jsx**

`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        fetchBooks: favoriteSubject => dispatch(getBooksList(favoriteSubject)),
        fetchSubjects: _ => dispatch(getSubjectsList())
    });`

So, this component correctly dispatches `getSubjectsList` and I can use `fetchSubjects` as props on `componentDidMount`. Similarly, it dispatches another action `getBooksList(favoriteSubject)` according to the chosen subject and `fetchBooks` can be used as props on `handleChange` callback (These actions make API request; in fact, all does)

2. **BookList.jsx**

`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        fetchBookDetails: bookId => dispatch(getBookDetails(bookId))
    });`

So, this component correctly dispatches `getBookDetails` action on `handleEdit` which is Edit button callback.

3. **BookEdit.jsx**

`const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        book: state.book.bookDetails,
        ...
    }...
    render() {
        const { bookDetails, loading, error } = this.props.book;
        ...
    }`

Now, this component keeps on waiting to re-render but it never receives the props. I see the actions, reducers dispatching correctly in the console (from `BooksList.jsx` component) but never see them reflecting on screen.

**How SO answers are not helping me get out of this situation**: I saw answers where it's specified that redux does a shallow comparison and if it doesn't find a subtle difference in the previous and next state then it skips rendering the app. However, as mentioned in the third step I see the action and reducer with previous and next state correctly.

Comment: You'll probably need to show more of the code involved in order to get a useful answer. Try to simplify your code to the simplest thing that still demonstrates the problem (e.g. eliminate the subject choice, just have single book in your book list, replace the API request with returning hard-coded json) and then show all the relevant code.

Comment: Curious ... How are BookEdit.jsx receiving the props? Are you sending in them from BookList.jsx? 

And your destructuring of props ... Your'e destructuring the prop named book from this.props.book ... Are the loading and error props in the book object also? Otherwise they won't be destructured.

Comment: Love the back of the envelope work, but checkout draw.io when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

If BookEdit isn't connected to the store or the props aren't being passed from a parent component you will not have access to them. Either connect your BookEdit...

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux;
...
const mapStateToProps = ({ book }) => {
  const { bookDetails, loading, error } = book;
  return { bookDetails, loading, error };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookEdit);
```

Or pass them in from a parent connected component that is bringing in props from your store.

Comment: Edited the question. Sorry, I missed the details about `mapStateToProps` for **BookEdit.jsx** component that I'm using. Which means this component is connected to store and that's expecting props (bookDetails, loading, error) in render().

Comment: Did you dive too far into your state? If you saved book as state.book.bookDetails instead of state.book and you're trying to destructure bookDetails instead of book? Also, are you able to log props at all?

Comment: Thank you so much helping me think in that direction. The change is `const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  book: state.book.book,...` where first `book` is an alias of `bookReducer` and next `book` is the state object of `bookReducer`. So, basically, I was accessing incorrect object property.

Answer (score 0):

Every time Redux actions are dispatched, `mapStateToProps` will be executed. The connect function from react-redux will only re-render your component when the props from `mapStateToProps` are not equal to the previous props.

Comment: Edited the question. Sorry, I missed the details about `mapStateToProps` for **BookEdit.jsx** component that I'm using. Which means this component is connected to store and that's expecting props (bookDetails, loading, error) in render().